# Link to Show Desktop in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a link I can put in my dock that will minimize every window and just show the desktop? Or, can this be accomplished with a keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 5):

Any time you are in Finder (or a save dialog), hit <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>.

Using the trackpad, you can do the "pinch out" gesture with your thumb and three fingers to reveal the desktop.

[image]

On my Logitech G500, I have bound the middle button to show the desktop in System Preferences.

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to show the desktop on Mac

**4 finger swipe**

http://www.apple.com/osx/what-is/gestures.html

**Create a shortcut**
[image]

http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1307399

**Hot Corners & Keyboard Shortcut (F12)**

[image]

**Download Hide All**

Checkout this page for instructions on how to setup Hide All, a program to hide all active apps.

http://www.instructables.com/id/Show-desktop-in-mac-osx-aka-hide-all/